# Repeating multiple images with CSS repeat-x

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I'm making a UHD project that requires displaying huge images. There's no problem with stationary browsers however iOS and some mobile browsers are very limited in that field. The max resolution for iOS PNG is 5 megapixels which is far lower than most of the images that I need to display.

Jpeg and other formats are not an option.

So far I decided to split big images into smaller ones and I've encountered a problem.
I've created a fiddle to show what's going on.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xz4p/1/)

As you can see I used 2 images in "background-image" to show the exact problem. The first image (circle) appears on top of the second (square).

Here is the code for CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
              body { overflow-x: hidden;
              background-image: url('http://www.clipartbest.com/download?clipart=di7eRd49T'), url('http://i126.photobucket.com/albums/p89/robertthomas_2006/600x600.png');
          background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
              background-position: left, right;
              }
```

And jQuery:

```
    $(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
        x-=1;
        $('body').css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
    }, 10);
    });
```

So the problem is that both "small" images are not side by side. There's no problem if I stitch them back in 1 big image. However mobile devices cannot handle it.

As far as I can see the "background-postion" in my css is ignored for some reason.

SO is there a way to apply "background-repeat: repeat-x" to the whole  block of background images and put images side by side?

I need from 2 to 10 background images to be repeated as the "organic whole" at the same time.

Is it possible with the method I'm using? If not - what is the best solution?

Comment: Why not use css @media queries to render mobile specific styles

Comment: Couple of reasons: they're progressing too fast. Some of them have 4"-5" displays with more resolution than stationary 23"-24" displays.Today's mobile devices are capable of handling most of regular webpages. Besides @media handheld for example refers only to those ancient tiny proto-html cellphones from years past which couldn't even really display web pages. The ePUB, MOBI, Tablet, community of vendors all said emphatically "H*ck no, we are not "@media handheld" devices!" because they were correctly worried that this would land them forever in a no-man's land subservient to "real" web pages.

Comment: I would not use device specific media queries, I would have used something along the lines of @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px), it's always worked well for me when i develop responsive websites.

Comment: I don't see how that's gonna help if iOS can't even start handling source image. Can you please provide a jsfiddle example with 6 megapixel (or bigger) png that will be rendered correctly on iOS? In any case - thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Well the background property is not in any way comfortable for doing what you want to do. I advice you then to place the images in a div, which div in other hand could be displayed below the other content (with position absolute), so it acts as a background. Note that you have to set z-index to your content also, and it should be a higher number than the z-index of your "background" div.
Again I advice you not to repeat the whole set of images endlessly, but rather start the animation again when it reaches the last one.
Give me a comment if you need a deeper explanation of something form above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't think that you quite understood what I am trying to achieve. I need to place 2 (or 5 or 20) images like this []O and repeat that formation horizontally endlessly. Your method offers me [O] this formation endlessly repeating horizontally and vertically. Neither the formation nor the repeating is correct.

Comment: I did get confused a bit, and I also didn't see that the circle actually had white background. The whole answer is changed, take a look at it.